# Glue can't read S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

## Description

Synced the data from other account by rclone, enabled the 'acl=bucket-owner-full-control'.

```sh
rclone sync 607562784642://cdh-bba-itdata-sub-cmdb-src-lt7g 162611943124://bbatest
```

When I cataloged the bucket data into Glue catalog by Crawler. Glue Crawler raised the following error

```
[49b1d1bd-d3f0-4801-9668-04f8651b06f4] ERROR : Not all read errors will be logged. com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: CD0062EA0B2D0AA7; S3 Extended Request ID: k0oHoKviPcWAs8yrn+9daImiTZ0Fx6sssbGiPF/7YwTjxUwITSDQHd2uTgh3K6QAcxDkvzHREJA=), S3 Extended Request ID: k0oHoKviPcWAs8yrn+9daImiTZ0Fx6sssbGiPF/7YwTjxUwITSDQHd2uTgh3K6QAcxDkvzHREJA=
```

[Official Check list](https://aws.amazon.com/cn/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-troubleshoot-403/)

I have checked items as per [Official Check list](https://aws.amazon.com/cn/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/s3-troubleshoot-403/).

- bucket owner ID
- object owner ID
  Both of them were same. There wasn't additional bucket policy.
- vpc endpoints
- bucket policy
- IAM policy

All policy didn't block glue to access S3 bucket.

The Crawler cataloged other bucket data successfully. So the glue configuration was correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bucket enabled customer managed key.
But I forgot to add glue role to kms.